# downloaded "thunderbird" and "firefox for developers", problem in installation

Tags: software-installation

I just downloaded the latest version of Mozilla Firefox For Developers and Thunderbird Mail, from the mozilla's official site... 
Both are **.tar.bz2** files, I just clicked on it, but they are not executing. 
Tried a lot of the other resources, tried the methods mentioned in the best questions on askubuntu.com too, but couldn't installed it. 
How can you I install them, if anyone can tell me the correct way please. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: its not a duplicate of "what you mentioned" :/ I tried the method mentioned in the question before,but its not working fine, and there isn't any **INSTALL** file or **./config** directory or **readme** file... @astrob0t

Comment: @Jack then you have downloaded the binary packages. Extract them, then run the `firefox` file in the extracted folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
mv /home/user/downloads/firefox-*.tar.bz2 /opt
mv /home/user/downloads/thunderbird-*.tar.bz2 /opt
cd /opt
tar xjf firefox-*.tar.bz2
tar xjf thunderbird-*.tar.bz2
chmod -Rf 777 /opt
```

To start Firefox, run the firefox script in the firefox folder: /opt/firefox/firefox

To start Thunderbird, run the thunderbird script in the thunderbird folder: /opt/thunderbird/thunderbird

To replace the original versión to developers versión:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
cd /usr/bin
mv firefox firefox_old
mv thunderbird thunderbird_old
ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
ln -s /opt/thunderbird/thunderbird /usr/bin/thunderbird
```