# How do I install the Firefox Developer Edition?

Tags: firefox

Mozilla released the Firefox Developer Edition! How do I install it on Ubuntu?

Source:

- [Mozilla Releases 'Firefox Developer Edition' for Windows, Mac and Linux - OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/11/mozilla-releases-firefox-developer-edition)

Comment: Um, reading the whole article, there's a link for download at the bottom?  That would be a good place to start!

Comment: You could have answered this one directly: http://askubuntu.com/questions/547987/downloaded-thunderbird-and-firefox-for-developers-problem-in-installation And please try to  use first party links (https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/11/mozilla-introduces-the-first-browser-built-for-developers-firefox-developer-edition/) instead of third-party ones.

Comment: Since Firefox Developer Edition is a tool designed for developper, I suggest you to validate the answer that explain how to install it with the official ubuntu installer called ubuntu-make (umake) : http://askubuntu.com/a/584704/85273

Comment: @cm-t I edit my answer on how to install F.D.E with Ubuntu Make!

Answer (score 303, accepted):

### Firefox Developer Edition

---

The Firefox Developer Edition is a modified version of Firefox, specifically designed for web developers. It uses a [separate profile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Developer_Edition#A_separate_profile) than the regular version of Firefox. Meaning you can have both Firefox or F-beta, installed next to the developer edition. Note that your F.D.E. will be a completely UN-customized browser. To unify settings, you can use [Firefox sync](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-up-firefox-sync).

Here's one of many perks when using F.D.E:

> "By using the Developer Edition, you gain access to tools and platform features at least 12 weeks before they reach the main Firefox release channel." - [Developer Edition - Mozilla | MDN#The_latest_Firefox_features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Developer_Edition#The_latest_Firefox_features)

### Installation

---

There are currently three ways to do this, manually, PPA or via [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make).

### Manually

---

Download from [Mozilla Firefox Developer Edition webpage](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/). Extract it with `file-roller` and move the folder to its final location. A good practice is to install it in `/opt/` or `/usr/local/`.

Once you moved the files to their final location (say `/opt/firefox_dev/`), you can create the following file `~/.local/share/applications/firefox_dev.desktop` to get a launcher with an icon distinct from normal Firefox.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox Developer 
GenericName=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/opt/firefox_dev/firefox %u
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/firefox_dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;X-Developer;
Comment=Firefox Developer Edition Web Browser.
StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition
```

Please note, that the parameter `StartupWMClass` is added to prevent duplicate icons in the launcher, [as explained here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403766/duplicate-icons-for-manually-created-gnome-launcher-items/635839#635839).

To mark the launcher as trusted, make it executable:

```
chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/firefox_dev.desktop
```

To launch it, navigate to ~/.local/share/applications/ using your "Files" application (ensure you turn on hidden folders), then double-click firefox_dev.desktop. Alternatively, search for `Firefox Developer`, and simply run the `firefox` binary, and voilà.

Note that, when you install manually, the F.D.E. does not have the unity global menu by default.

### PPA

---

Firefox for developers currently resides in [Firefox Aurora builds : “Ubuntu Mozilla Daily Build Team” team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-aurora). It should be noted that:

> "Firefox Developer Edition replaces the Aurora channel in the [Firefox Release Process](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Release_Management/Release_Process). Like Aurora, features will land in the Developer Edition every six weeks, after they have stabilized in Nightly builds." - [Developer Edition - Mozilla | MDN #The_latest_Firefox_features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Developer_Edition#The_latest_Firefox_features)

Also:

> "Version 35.0a2, first offered to Firefox Developer Edition users on November 10, 2014" - [Firefox — Aurora Notes (35.0a2) — Mozilla#main-content](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/35.0a2/auroranotes/#main-content)

Install the Firefox Developer Edition, formerly know as Aurora, like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

The Mozilla PPA only holds packages for the supported Ubuntu releases, not EOL(End Of Life) releases.

Note that installing with the aforementioned ppa, will result in your current Firefox installation being replaced!

### Ubuntu Make

This method has been provided by [Jorge Castro](https://askubuntu.com/a/584704/36315). I am adding this here, because it's also an excellent way to install the Firefox Developer Edition(and many others dev tools).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

After you have installed ubuntu-make, tell it to install the `web` tool `firefox-dev`.

```
umake web firefox-dev
```

### Uninstall

---

If you wish to keep the Current default Firefox, because The FDE has no new features you like, or for whatever reason, here are a few ways to uninstall it.

#### PPA

---

You can remove the ppa, and its packages, using ppa-purge.

Install it like so:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

The following will remove the PPA, and its packages:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
```

#### Manually

---

remove the binaries with the `rm` command(rename the path to the location you actually extracted FDE). Or with your file-manager:

```
sudo rm -r /opt/firefox_dev/
```

Also remove the `firefox_dev.desktop`

```
sudo rm ~/.local/share/applications/firefox_dev.desktop
```

After that you have successfully removed the Firefox Developer Edition.

### Ubuntu Make

the following command will remove Firefox Developer Edition:

```
umake web firefox-dev -r
```

You can also remove umake and its PPA (`ppa-purge` needed, see installation instructions above):

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
```

### Screenshot

[image]

 <sup>Firefox Developer Edition on Ubuntu 14.04.1</sup>

### Change Theme

At the time of writing, there are three themes available for F.D.E. Here is how to enable them.

Type in the url bar:

> about:config

When in the search filter type in `theme`. Then double click on `devtools.theme`. After that, type in `light`, and the theme will be applied.

[image: Multiple FDE themes]

<sup>Screenshot with multiple themes available for F.D.E.</sup>

### Features

---

Some - but not all - features touted by Mozilla:

- **WebIDE**:

  - allows you to develop, deploy and debug Web apps directly in your browser, or on a Firefox OS device. It lets you create a new Firefox OS app (which is just a web app) from a template, or open up the code of an existing app. From there you can edit the app’s files. It’s one click to run the app in a simulator and one more to debug it with the developer tools.
  - [Web IDE - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1R9_WdXwUsE)
- **Valence**:

  - (previously called Firefox Tools Adapter) lets you develop and debug your app across multiple browsers and devices by connecting the Firefox dev tools to other major browser engines. Valence also extends the awesome tools we’ve built to debug [Firefox OS](https://developer.mozilla.org/Firefox_OS) and [Firefox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&hl=en) to the other major mobile browsers including Chrome on Android and Safari on iOS. So far these tools include our Inspector, Debugger and Console and Style Editor.
  - [Valence - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eH0R10Ga4Hs)
- **Responsive Design Mode**:

  - see how your website or Web app will look on different screen sizes without changing the size of your browser window.
- **Page Inspector**:

  - examine the HTML and CSS of any Web page and easily modify the structure and layout of a page.
- **Web Console**:

  - see logged information associated with a Web page and use Web Console and interact with a Web page using JavaScript.
- **JavaScript Debugger**:

  - step through JavaScript code and examine or modify its state to help track down bugs.
- **Network Monitor**:

  - see all the network requests your browser makes, how long each request takes and details of each request.
- **Style Editor**:

  - view and edit CSS styles associated with a Web page, create new ones and apply existing CSS stylesheets to any page.
- **Web Audio Editor**:

  - inspect and interact with Web Audio API in real time to ensure that all audio nodes are connected in the way you expect.

**Reference**:

---

- [Mozilla Introduces the First Browser Built For Developers: Firefox Developer Edition ✩ Mozilla Hacks – the Web developer blog](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/11/mozilla-introduces-the-first-browser-built-for-developers-firefox-developer-edition/)
- [Firefox — Aurora Notes (35.0a2) — Mozilla](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/35.0a2/auroranotes/)(Firefox Developer Edition Notes)

  - Version 35.0a2, first offered to Firefox Developer Edition users on November 10, 2014
- [Firefox Developer Edition — Mozilla](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/)
- [Firefox Aurora builds : “Ubuntu Mozilla Daily Build Team” team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-aurora)
- [Developer Edition - Mozilla | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Developer_Edition)

Comment: Yeah - I got that far too. But a) where does one put in in the directory tree after that (I did /usr/lib just like regular firefox, after renaming the folder to firefoxdev)?

And b) how do I get the icon into the launcher, and how do I get the search boxto find it?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne No, that's wrong. You shouldn't manually place programs in that location or anywhere else than `/opt/`, `/usr/local/…`, your home directory or removable media. `/opt/`, is probably better than `/usr/local/…`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard For launcher icons see: http://askubuntu.com/q/13758/40581

Comment: Excellent answer, much appreciated over the smarmy "read harder" comments. Thanks.

Comment: addendum: manual install doesn't have unity global menu, version from PPA does.

Comment: Thanks! That worked beautifully. Small issue: the colors are horrendous, it's actually causing usability issues. Is there a way to revert to the old theme? I tried changing the firefox theme that only changes some things. The background color of my scrollbars and input fields is a mess. I can't see what I'm typing.

Comment: @Costa Updated my answer!

Comment: Note: the PPA method packages it as `firefox` which means you can't (AFAICS) have regular firefox and developer firefox installed via `apt` at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. Works like a charm. However, the icon is not working. Anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Using the ppa does nothing, I'm still stuck with the non-dev version of firefox; umake just outputs ``ERROR: Download page changed its syntax or is not parsable``.

Comment: Thanks! For the record, to have Konsole (under KDE) open the URL links properly with manual install, I had to append `%u` at the end of `Exec=/opt/firefox_dev/firefox %u` line in the application-related file `~/.local/share/applications/firefox_dev.desktop`.

Comment: I created the entry under ~/.local/share/applications/firefox_dev.desktop as suggested. I still do not have the distinct icon for firefox dev. Please advise.

Comment: Looks like the Aurora PPA was deprecated. Not sure why...

Comment: @solstice333 Because now, Firefox dev is based on the Beta channel and not Aurora. But I still can't find up to date install instructions.

Comment: aurora PPA doesnt install firefox dev edition. not firefox-next PPA . Only way is umake and tar installation now

Comment: Using the PPA method I am told `Users of this PPA need to use ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next in addition to receive continuous updates!`. Could you please add a note, or if the PPA method is unusable right now remove it altogether? Thanks!

Comment: I followed the PPA instructions (and also added `ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next` as suggested), but `firefox -v` just returns `Mozilla Firefox 61.0`.

Comment: Just install version 62.0b8 using the manual instructions. Everything worked except the icon path is now /opt/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png instead of .../mozicon128.png

Comment: For changing theme, from the top left menu -> customize -> near the bottom, you can choose themes

Comment: Manual installation works nice, except for the icon shortcut in the toolbar: when you click on the icon, it duplicates it at the end of the bar, thus defeating the purpose of the icon (Win+number won't work as expected among others)... 
Any ideas on how to fix the icon behavior so that it behaves normally?

Comment: Manual version worked great on Debian, which I guess you'd expect, but just to confirm!

Comment: Also, be sure to **set write permissions for your users in `/opt/firefox_dev` so that Firefox can auto-update**! e.g. using custom group: `sudo addgroup writeapps`; `sudo chgrp writeapps /opt/firefox_dev -R`; `sudo chmod g+w /opt/firefox_dev -R`; `sudo adduser $USER writeapps` ... (or just use o+w to grant write to anyone)

Comment: ... also (for custom group access) `sudo chmod g+s` on `/opt/firefox_dev` and every subfolder to make files created by Firefox on update inherit group `writeapps`. Then you can have a mode like `770` on `/opt/firefox_dev` and let only users in this group run and update Firefox.

Comment: thanks for the help with the manual installation. A couple small things to change for the desktop entry. If anyone doesn't know, you edit this the same as a text-file (open it in your text editor and save the above.
Necessary corrections to [Desktop Entry] :
Exec command should be `/opt/firefox_dev/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default`
Icon path should be `/opt/firefox_dev/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png`

Comment: For me to get the ".desktop" file working I had to change "Exec" value from "firefox-developer" (which just didn't work) to the full path (used in "TryExec"). I've also made the file executable. Thank You by the way (especially the information about Ubuntu Make)!

Comment: Firefox developer edition is saying it has updates. How do I get updates to install automatically? Or what do I have to do to install them? Can you update your post?

Answer (score 31):

The Firefox Developer Edition is available as part of [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

After that just run the Firefox installer as your user (don't use sudo in this case):

```
umake web firefox-dev
```

It will prompt you where to install Firefox, and then download it automatically and install it.

If you are using ubuntu (unity), in the launcher, a new icon *Firefox Developer Edition* has been pinned. Click on it to launch your freshly installed *Firefox Developer Edition*.

*Firefox Developer Edition* will prompt itself for auto-updates (will not use apt).

Comment: From Ubuntu 15.04 on you can install the package `ubuntu-make` from the main repositories.

Comment: The PPA only provides Ubuntu Make packages, with the name: `ubuntu-make` not `umake`!

Comment: Thx.. it's easier to use your guide than the answers above :)

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04.1 I had to use the PPA. The `ubuntu-make` in main repo is outdated and gives `ERROR: Download page changed its syntax or is not parsable`. The PPA version works fine.

Comment: @jorge-castro  Is this daily build and update automatically?

Comment: When installing manually, how to enable the unity global menu?

Comment: After entering the first sudo line I keep receiving this error: "Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu/ubuntu-make'.
ERROR: '~ubuntu-desktop' user or team does not exist."
̉Has anything changed since the post? Am I misunderstanding anything (Iḿ new to Ubuntu)

Comment: Followed all the steps. No error. But no firefox developer edition that I can run... At least not under 'Activities '. Writing 'FIrefox' on Ubuntu search only shows the standard Firefox, not this. Yet uner `.local/share/applications/` there a `firefox-developer.destop` file, but clicking on it gives `untrusted aplication launcher` error. How do I launch it?

Comment: There's also a `firefox` executable in `.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev/`, but executing doesn't make it available on ubuntu search for applications. Nor it is displayed in the `Activities` menu, nor can be pinned on the taskbar. It runs as when you just download Firefox from the internet and click on it, as if it werent totally installed as the other apps...

Comment: I had to switch to the ppa `ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make` in order to get a working umake command. It's the one pointed out in the [project's Readme.md](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make)

Comment: I was getting an error in the installation that said `ERROR: One default was already registered, can't register a second one in that choices set:`, to solve this just install like this: `umake web firefox-dev --lang en-US` or with any other language

Answer (score 14):

First download firefox dev from [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/). Then run the following commands *(make sure `/from` is changed to the location of the files you downloaded)*.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel 
sudo mv /from to /opt/firefox_dev/
sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) /opt/firefox_dev/
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/.local/share/applications --create-new
```

then just search it in unity

Comment: For `gnome-desktop-item-edit`, you will have to install `gnome-panel`: `apt-get install gnome-panel`.

Comment: gnome-desktop-item-edit [is removed](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-panel/commit/758b548aa9d2b920b6e91664b0de9c414b65f2e9) from the gnome-panel package, it won't be available for Ubuntu 19.10 (and most likely later releases). [Alternative methods can be found here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-panel/commit/758b548aa9d2b920b6e91664b0de9c414b65f2e9)

Answer (score 7):

1. Download the tar.bz2 file from https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/
2. In the terminal, extract the tar (`tar xvjf filename.tar.bz2`)
3. Go into the new directory where the files have been extracted to. For me it was called `firefox/`
4. Type `./firefox`

Comment: how do you make it update-able, if update comes how does it work ?

Comment: simple and easy

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do, if you don't have gnome-panel/gnome-desktop-item-edit installed, is create a `.desktop` file manually.

You can run this:

```
sudo mv /from_where_it_is to /opt/firefox_dev/
sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) /opt/firefox_dev/
```

then run (you can obviously swap out `nano` for whatever app you want to use):

```
sudo nano ~/.local/share/applications/firefox_dev.desktop
```

and enter the following (or change it around how you like):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=35.0a2                                  # version of the app.
Name[en_US]=firefox_dev                         # name of the app.
GenericName=Firefox Developer Edition           # longer name of the app.
Exec=/opt/firefox_dev/firefox                   # command used to launch the app.
Terminal=false                                  # whether the app requires to be run in a terminal.
Icon[en_US]=firefox                             # location of icon file - Firefox Dev currently has no icon of its own, so just using the system default for Firefox
Type=Application                                # type.
Categories=Application;Network;Developer;       # categories in which this app should be listed.
Comment[en_US]=Firefox Developer Edition Web Browser. # comment which appears as a tooltip.
```

Comment: Putting the .desktop file into that folder wasn't enough for me. Instead, right click the file, click Properties, turn on the "run as executable" permission, and double click the file. FF Dev Edition should launch. Right click its icon in the launcher and lock it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in your Downloads folder [credit @blade19899]:

```
tar xjf  firefox-36.0a2.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 
sudo mv firefox/   /opt/firefox_dev/
sudo gedit ~/.local/share/applications/firefox_dev.desktop
```

Now copy and paste `[Desktop Entry]` as mentioned in manual installation.

Comment: "sudo mv /firefox ..." I doubt this is correct. A firefox dir in root?

Comment: @Rinzwind Well it works.That's where we put it when we want it to be executable from dash.

Comment: @srbh: the issue is that it seems that you have put stuff in ``/``, even if you stated that you are working in ``Download`` folder, you shouldn´t put explicitly copy/pastable code that needs to be tinkered to work. Just add a simple ``cd ~/Downloads``, and correct your ``mv`` line. Yet, the best would be to use ``wget`` and work in ``/tmp`` to have fully copy&pastable code that downloads and install it. If you can also avoid fixing the version of firefox (which renders this code obsolete extra quickly), this would be greater. And a link is missing to make firefox executable from ``$PATH``.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug for for my own solution to this problem: I made a `.deb` package for Mozilla's tar and published it in releases section of the Github repo that houses the sources for the packaging scripts.

The repo is located here: https://github.com/wheelerlaw/firefoxdev

To install, run the following commands (assuming you have `jq` installed):

```
curl -fsSL "https://api.github.com/repos/wheelerlaw/firefoxdev/releases/latest" | jq '.assets[0].browser_download_url' | xargs curl -OL
sudo dpkg -i firefoxdev_*_.deb
```

Comment: Nice, works fine!  The following one can update it: `sudo wget -c "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-devedition-latest-ssl&os=linux64&lang=en-US" -O - | sudo tar -xj -C /opt && sudo rm -rf /opt/firefoxdev && sudo mv /opt/firefox /opt/firefoxdev`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a copy paste solution that just works. Doing things by hand seems to be the way to go on Linux. Tested working on Ubuntu 20.04.

```bash
# https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/
download_url=https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-devedition-latest-ssl&os=linux64&lang=en-CA
wget $download_url -O firefox.tar.bz2
tar -xjf firefox.tar.bz2
sudo mv firefox /opt/firefox-dev
sudo chown -R $(whoami): /opt/firefox-dev/
rm firefox.tar.bz2

desktop_file=~/.local/share/applications/firefox-dev.desktop
# use a heredoc to create desktop file directly
tee $desktop_file << EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Web Browser Developer Edition
Comment=Browse the WWW
GenericName=Web Browser
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web
Exec=/opt/firefox-dev/firefox %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;
StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=/opt/firefox-dev/firefox -new-window

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Exec=/opt/firefox-dev/firefox -private-window
EOF

# optional if you want `firefox` in your $PATH:
sudo ln -s /opt/firefox-dev/firefox /usr/local/bin/firefox
```

Updates can be done through the Firefox's general settings. Also remember to go change your default browser using Firefox settings. You might also want to update your `BROWSER` variable in your rc file (`~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you downloaded the file, it didn't get saved with executable permissions.

- Download the firefox developer edition here:
  https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/
- Extract the file manually to `/opt/firefox/`
- Open Nautilus: Go to `Edit->Preferences-> Behavior-> click on "Run
  executable text files when they are opened"`
- Go to the file `'firefox'` in `/opt/firefox/`
- Right click and select `Properties--> Permissions--> Execute: Allow
  executing file as a program.`
- Open terminal and type:

> gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/.local/share/applications --create-new

Create a shortcut and You're done !

If you're still unable to run it, you might be having problem with installing firefox even after following all the answers here. It might be because Firefox will not run at all without the following libraries or packages:

- GTK+ 2.18 or higher
- GLib 2.22 or higher
- Pango 1.14 or higher
- X.Org 1.0 or higher (1.7 or higher is recommended)
- libstdc++ 4.3 or higher

libstdc++ is not included in Ubuntu by default.

For optimal functionality, the following are the recommended libraries or packages:

- NetworkManager 0.7 or higher
- DBus 1.0 or higher
- HAL 0.5.8 or higher
- GNOME 2.16 or higher

To install a package, open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install [package-name]
```

I was not able to launch the executable script contained in file 'firefox' in firefox directory.

Comment: This doesn't really count as an answer to the question - you haven't answered how to 'install' the firefox developer edition.

Comment: @ThomasW. Yes, I assumed he must be having problem with running it after following the instructions here. Edited the answer to resolve a possible cause for the executable file not being able to run.

Comment: No "Edit" button or anything laleled 'Edit' in Nautilus (Ubuntu last 18 version -  Nautilus is called 'Files' here)... Is it something only available on older versions or are you referring to something else? And if the first case, do you know what is the equivalent now?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will add the firefox daily build to your repositories and install firefox-dev. As of writing this post, these version numbers match (35.0a2).

Comment: Did you actually try what I wrote, or did you just come here to tell me I'm wrong? I did exactly this and I'm working with a nicely installed version of Developer Edition, full suite of new dev tools included. In fact, the top answer here seems to have taken my solution.

Comment: at the time of your post, yes, I did try, and it wasn't the same build - looks like it's been updated since then, and maybe it was stale package data.  Maybe a bug in my system, but either way at the time of commenting it wasnt the same version

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to install manually (download, extract and create .desktop file)
following desktop sample can resolve problems like;

- duplicate icon show up on favorites bar
- right-click to 'open a new window' & 'private window'

Referenced PPA installed firefox desktop file.

Extracted under `/opt/firefox-dev/`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Web Browser Developer Edition
Comment=Browse the WWW
GenericName=Web Browser
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web
Exec=/opt/firefox-dev/firefox %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;
StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=/opt/firefox-dev/firefox -new-window

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Exec=/opt/firefox-dev/firefox -private-window
```

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the above answers mentioned snap which as of 2022 is the official way to install [umake](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make), Firefox Developer Edition can easily be installed on Ubuntu by:

```
snap install ubuntu-make --classic
```

After installation finished:

```
umake web firefox-dev
```