# Update Firefox Developer edition

Tags: updates, firefox, ppa

It seems the ppa for Firefox Developer Edition (formally aurora) is no longer active. I have installed Firefox Developer Edition from Firefox's website and installed it in `/opt/firefox`. Now it is asking me to update and I get a new tar file. Do I have to overwrite that directory every time I want to do an update? Of note, related post:

- [Can I use the Aurora PPA to install Firefox Developer Edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548196/can-i-use-the-aurora-ppa-to-install-firefox-developer-edition)
- [Firefox Developer Edition ppa not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885063/firefox-developer-edition-ppa-not-working)

do not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open the PPAs in a browser and navigate upwards?    That's all I did for this answer (*starting with a link from your provided link that gave me a **forbidden** error*)

You'll eventually see the PPA being used is

[https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

*This may not be all they provide - I just followed links to an alternative.*

Do note however - I have no experience using this 3rd party source; having never used it, thus cannot say this is what you're looking is suitable, fit for purpose, nor what you're actually looking for (even your *unstated* architecture).

Comment: I am looking for firefox developer edition, not firefox

Comment: You can look yourself as what they (Mozilla) provide; however they have opted to provide packages via *snap* for Ubuntu, as it gives Mozilla greater control; so *deb* packages options are now reduced on what they used to be.

Comment: to my knowledge they no longer offer developer edition via ppa, hence my question. So how do I update it? or how do I find the ppa if it does exist?

Comment: I would likely ask the question on a [Mozilla forums](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/forums/) as I'm largely limited to what I see with various projects with, which has included via Ubuntu News various statements from Mozilla & the future via *snap* but it was mostly general news & I don't know if it covered all products (eg. Developer Edition) as not being a user of it myself, I had no interest in remembering it.

Comment: I've checked the forums. So since I can't find the ppa and had to install it via deb. Now that it offers an update via deb, how do I install that?

Comment: This still doesn't answer my questoin

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the permissions of your install folder in /opt as such:
`sudo chown -R $(whoami): /opt/firefox/`

Comment: this does not answer the question at all. OP was asking *what is the best way to update* and did not indicate in any way that they were having permission issues.