# Remove Firefox developer edition

Tags: firefox

A couple of days ago I installed Firefox developer edition using the command line but it seems to have removed my 'standard' Firefox. No matter what I try I cannot get it back, I've followed guides online which say they completely remove Firefox but then when I reinstall it from the software center I'm using the developer edition again.

Is there a way to fix this?

I'd like to have both the standard & developer edition installed ideally.

Comment: How did you install the "developer edition" ? If you compiled it from source it may not be so easy ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not 100% sure, I'm still quite new to Linux. How would I know if it was from source? I know it was done through the command line.

Comment: Did you install it with apt-get ? make && make install ? software center ? Where did you get the package ?

Comment: Sorry for taking a while to reply. I'm pretty sure that I installed it with apt-get in the terminal window. Is that helpful?

Comment: yes, did you add a ppa or repository ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it wasn't ppa so must have been a repository. When I typed the command into the terminal I never entered "ppa" so I'm guessing it can't be that.

Comment: Open software center and look at what repositories you have enabled. If you installed firefox with apt it is just a mater of removing (purge) firefox, remove the developer repository, and re-install.

Comment: When I look in the software centre it says that I've got "Firefox Web Browser" but it mentions nothing about the developer edition, it does however have the same logo as the developer edition rather than the standard Firefox logo. I have uninstalled this before & done a purge from the command line then reinstalled it but I still ended up with the developer edition.

Comment: What version of Firefox and what version of Ubuntu ? run `firefox -v`

Comment: Again, sorry for the delayed reply I do appreciate your help.

When I run "firefox -v" in the terminal window I get a message saying "(process:2892): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Mozilla Firefox 35.0a2"

Comment: There is an uninstall section in here: [http://askubuntu.com/a/548005/36315](http://askubuntu.com/a/548005/36315)

Comment: @blade19899 Thank you so much, it's completely solved the problem! I even have Firefox developer edition install as well as the standard Firefox for use which is what I wanted. Should I leave this question without an accepted answer?

Comment: @NeilNand sure. I'll vote to close this Q, as a duplicate to the aforementioned uninstall section link.

Answer (score 2):

since my own installation of firefox developer edition did not show up in my list of installed programs, I got rid of firefox developer edition by manually doing common sense backtracking its installation via deleting it via > downloads > next > programs > etc... then finally a "delete" wizard installation box! ...lastly, do a pc restart. tom, 12-17-14.

Comment: Could you clarify that a bit more? What does "via > downloads > next > programs > etc" refer to? Directories?