# How to uninstall Firefox developer edition?

Tags: firefox, application-development, uninstall

I tried uninstalling it from Ubuntu software center. It gets uninstalled but if I re-install Firefox (not developer edition) then it switches to Firefox developer edition.

How do I ONLY uninstall Firefox developer but keep the bookmarks, URL etc. saved for the retro Mozilla Firefox browser. I don't want to loose any data while shifting from Firefox developer edition to the Mozilla Firefox browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Firefox developer edition](http://askubuntu.com/q/553330/36315)

Comment: @blade19899 I checked this thread, before asking and the answer is incomplete `Could you clarify that a bit more? What does "via > downloads > next > programs > etc" refer to? Directories?`

Comment: How did you install it in the first place?

Comment: @blade19899 `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next`
  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and I don't know its ask about the firefox dev edition update and unfortunately I clicked that

Comment: @blade19899 And from this thread I found the command http://www.libre-software.net/how-to-install-firefox-on-ubuntu-linux-mint

Comment: I am not aware that the firefox-next had the Firefox Developer edition, in it. But, you can revert to retro firefox, by doing `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` and then `ppa-purge ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next`. It will remove the ppa, and its packages, if your data willbe maintained, that i am not sure of..

Comment: If my answer answered your question, please accept it. If not, Feel free to `@blade19899` me.

Comment: Without knowing how you installed it, exactly (not just a link), we can't be sure how to remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove the Firefox Developer Edition from ppa, use ppa-purge.

First close the Firefox Developer Edition, then run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

And then remove the ppa:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
```

I am not sure if it will keep your Firefox data! But by using [Firefox Sync](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/sync/), you can backup everything just in case it deletes everything.

After that remove packages that FDE required, but are no longer needs.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then reinstall `firefox`:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Comment: OMG..its giving me the worst experience with Firefox this time..I run the above mentioned commands..and uninstall FF from ubuntu software center..now If I re install from ubuntu s/w center..its switching to the same developer edition..worst experience with firefox this time:(

Comment: @swapnesh ? If you runned: `ppa-purge ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next`, Firefox Developer Edition is already removed. Try on top of that: `sudo apt-get install firefox`. And then reinstall it `sudo apt-get install firefox`.

Comment: You can check in screenshot..its not going any how :( :( http://imgur.com/6YUq6Qo

Comment: @swapnesh, i will update my question, with further detailed steps to follow.

Comment: Let me know what I am doing wrong here..FYI somewhere in between I installed from this download bundle too `firefox-34.0.5.tar.bz2` ..let me know if they can also mess the things as well

Comment: @swapnesh I advice you to not do anything, follow the steps i posted on my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Had to uninstall this PPA.  The rest of the instructions worked as expected, and my original Firefox profile was restored.

```
sudo ppa-purge  ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who installed firefox developer edition using ubuntu-make, you can delete the symlink `~/.local/share/umake/bin/firefox-developer` and the folder `~/.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev`.

If you want to unkinstall umake completely, run

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-make
```

And then delete the folder `~/.local/share/umake`, as the purge will not remove it.

Comment: This works when you install using umake

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora I was able to simply rename the 'firefox' directory, reinstall firefox and reimport my bookmarks.  It is cleaner to remove the old directory if you prefer, but as they say if it works don't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your Firefox specific data to your Firefox Account (if you don't have one, it is super easy to set up: go to the three horizontal bars in the tool bar and click where it will say something about sign-in to account to sync).

Then use `apt` to remove the dev version of Firefox. Be sure to run `sudo apt autoremove` to remove any leftover configuration files. (Personally, I would also reboot to ensure any old files are removed. But this is not entirely necessary). Then, go and use `apt`, `synaptic`, or the software center to re-install Firefox.

Finally, log into your Firefox Account and all your bookmarks, settings, and add-ons will be copied over to the new installation for you.

Hope this helped!