# How do I make Firefox Developer Edition my default browser?

Tags: firefox, launcher, shortcuts, default

I want to make fde my browser by default, I installed it following [this guy's video](http://youtu.be/JO9NdpK9z_E) and clicked the "Use firefox developer edition as my default browser" but when I closed and tried to open it again using the shortcut I thought I had made for it on the launcher, only the regular firefox launches.

Will I have to `sudo nautilus` every time I want to open it?

How can i make the blue icon shortcut for it on the launcher?

- I read [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition/548005#548005) to it but can't really understand what he is saying, could you show me through screenshots?
- I also tried [this solution offered below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565748/how-do-i-make-firefox-developer-edition-my-default-browser/566092#566092) and got this as result (even though I      killedall firefox     instances):
  [image: photo]

Comment: Try creating a symbolic link, like: `sudo ln -sf /opt/firefox-dev/firefox /usr/bin/firefox`. Here /opt/firefox-dev/ is the folder you use to run it. Source: http://linuxg.net/firefox-developer-edition-35-alpha-2-has-been-released-installation-instructions-for-the-most-popular-linux-systems/

Comment: i don't understand your answer, what is that? what do i do?

Answer (score 1):

Up until now, what you are doing is clicking the firefox dev edition's executable after you find it via nautilus (do not use sudo, it is not needed). But to launch an application in the usual way, you need a launcher file.

You can create a launcher file using the application **menulibre**. It is available in the Software Center.

Launch it, select "**Add Launcher**" and create a launcher for Firefox Dev Edition. For the "command" field, click on the folder icon, navigate to the file that you click to open the Firefox Developer Edition and select that.

Give it the name and icon that you want (leave the 'working directory' option empty), and you have a new application. You can add that to the Unity Launcher, and you can set it as default through **System Settings**>**Details**>**Default Applications**.

**EDIT:**

This error message means that you have another instance of Firefox running. You can't run Firefox if it is already running, so you get this error message.
Make sure that you are not running Firefox (neither version) and try again.
If you get the same error message, kill all Firefox instances with the command

```
killall firefox
```

and if that doesn't work, then kill all Firefox instances with the command

```
sudo killall firefox
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said and got [this](http://i.imgur.com/pabgEqP.jpg) as result, i also got it using nautilus without sudo, but with sudo i can open it.

Comment: I killedall firefox instances, but get the exact same result as before.

Comment: Log out and log back in then.

Comment: I did that, same result.

Comment: I tried using menulibre as you suggested, but I never got past the stage after I "saved" the new launcher in menulibre. When you say - "Give the name and icon that you want.....you have a new application", can you specify what you mean? How do I find the new application?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have opened the Firefox Developer Edition, right click its icon in the Launcher and select the Lock to Launcher option. Now, the icon is permanently added to the launcher.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer my question, that was the first thing i tried, coming from windows 7 i was used to that practice but didn't work, there's no blue icon to begin with and the firefox browser attached to the launcher is the regular firefox.

Comment: As you followed the mentioned video in your question, you would have the Firefox Developed Edition and execute its binary file. Did you execute its binary file from its Developer Edition folder?

Comment: Yes, I did execute its binary file from its Developer Edition folder.

Comment: If you have executed it, you should find a Firefox Developer Edition icon in the launcher. Right click it and select the "Lock to Launcher" option. If you already have a general firefox icon in the launcher and having difficulty in finding difference of both icon, before executing the Developer Edition, remove the existing general firefox icon from the launcher by right clicking it and selecting the "Unlock from Launcher" option. You could now open the Developer Edition and lock it to launcher.

Comment: I also tried that one my first attempts at getting into it, but didn't work either. The icon that gets attached to the launcher only shortcuts to the normal Firefox.

Comment: What about removing general-purpose firefox and having only developer edition one? Because maybe that's the only option is considered for now.

Comment: I am going to leave that as a final option, I also use regular Firefox along with FDE.