# How can I make Firefox Developer Edition my default browser?

Tags: unity, firefox

I just manually installed Firefox Developer Edition by extracting the tarball to a folder in my `/home` directory, creating a .desktop launcher and putting that in `/home/.local/share/applications`. Now I can't set FDE as the default browser. No matter how many times I launch it and hit "yes" on the "make default browser" prompt, that prompt comes up the next time I launch it, and it's still not default.

When I go into Settings > Details > Default Applications, the drop-down menu for "Web Browser" only contains the old Firefox and something called "Browser". How can I make Ubuntu see FDE?

Comment: Note: I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565748/how-do-i-make-firefox-developer-edition-my-default-browser), but it's written in a very confused way and the answers don't really address the problem, in particular FDE not showing up in the settings menu isn't mentioned. Maybe that question should be closed as a duplicate of this one.