# Installing Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: software-installation, firefox

I want to use Firefox Developer Edition separated from the normal Firefox so I need two short cuts for the launcher, one for the regular Firefox and another one for Firefox Developer Edition.

I am following the guide posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition/548005#548005), being a complete newbie, just moving the firefox folder to /opt/firefox_dev/ was a challenge, now I've managed to get to here:

[image: Following guide]

Notice that I made some changes from the original code to the code on my Terminal to make directories match.

What do I do now?

I thought that pressing Enter would be it, but I'm stuck at this point, what do I do next to follow the guide posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at that point I just had to press ctrl + x, I didn't know that, but an user pointed out [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54221/how-to-edit-files-in-a-terminal-with-nano) for me and that was it.

Thank you.