# Create a .desktop file: cannot find the icon on my desktop

Tags: firefox

I am trying to install Firefox Dev and followed this: [How do I install the Firefox Developer Edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition)

I created, with nano, a file: `firefox_dev.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications/firefox_dev.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox Developer 
GenericName=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/opt/firefox_dev/firefox
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/firefox_dev/browser/icons/mozicon128.png
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;X-Developer;
Comment=Firefox Developer Edition Web Browser.
```

And I'm stuck; how do I launch it?

Comment: You mean in Dash? There should be no icon on your desktop.

Comment: If you followed that link then also recheck your paths for Exec= & Icon=. Ex. from that link for Exec= it would be `Exec=/opt/firefox_dev/firefox/firefox` An invalid .desktop will not show up in the Dash.

Comment: The dash doesn't immediately show changes. Best log out and in again and then it should show up.

Comment: @Raphael_b: E allora? did logging out and back in work???  ;-)  Anyway, it's best to take another icon then the standard mozilla one so you can recognize the 2 easily: I use [this one](http://rocketdock.com/addon/icons/41484)

Comment: @Fabby Yes log in log out seemed to be the solution. Thanks guys

Comment: THIS IS NOT  "problem that can't be reproduced that seemingly went away on its own". It has been answered. Don't abuse the close reason.

Comment: chmod +x on the .desktop, launch with windows key

Answer (score 3):

Just log out and then log back in…  That should do the trick!

**Low-quality queue reviewers: That's it as per comments...**

Comment: `touch ~/.local/share/applications/firefox_dev.desktop`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your that your path of `Exec`,`Icon` and other `paths` are correct.
This are the contents of my `firefox.desktop` file.

```
[Desktop Entry]

Name=Firefox 
GenericName=Firefox
Exec=/home/myapps/firefox/firefox-69.0.1/firefox/firefox
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/myapps/firefox/firefox-69.0.1/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;X-Developer;
Comment=Firefox Developer Edition Web Browser.
```

where `firefox` at the end of "Exec" is "ELF 64-bit LSB executable", make sure that you mention that too.