# How to install Firefox developer edition separately from Firefox stable in Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox

There are many instructions in Internet how to replace stable version of Firefox in Ubuntu to Firefox developer edition. But many users want to have both versions of Firefox at the same time.

Did anybody know ppa or other method to install Firefox Developer edition as separate deb package, named not "firefox", but something like "firefox-developer-edition" or "firefox-aurora", for keep current stable version of Firefox unchanged?

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition) is examples how to replace current stable Firefox version by Developer edition, but I want to have both versions installed on system at the same time. So deb package for Firefox Developer Edition must have another name, different that "firefox".

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate, I want to install separate Firefox Developer Edition with keep Firefox Stable installed.

Comment: Yes, it is. Take some effort to read through the linked answers.