# I can only install Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: firefox

I installed Firefox  Nightly Developer Edition so I could contribute to some of their open source projects.

I'd like to change back to the original. I've uninstalled Firefox using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

then

```
ppa-purge ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
```

then

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

But every time I go to install Firefox, either via the terminal or the Ubuntu Software Center, it installs the Developer Edition.

Does anyone know how to install the traditional Firefox? In a perfect world, I'd like to have both so I could still contribute and not need to worry about the bugs when I'm at work.

Comment: add the output `apt-cache policy firefox`

Comment: Did you use sudo in the purge like so `sudo ppa-purge ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how I missed it, but [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition/548005#548005) had what I needed,

If you don't want to click, here is the short answer to properly uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

then

```
ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
```