# How to make Firefox (versions 41+) accept unsigned extensions?

Tags: apt, firefox, browser

Since Mozilla decided for coercing people to hand-in their Firefox-Browser extensions for signing by Mozilla, else they would not run in newer (41+) versions of the browser, it seems to me the firefox to be found in the standard Ubuntu repository would make most of my own, not signed, extensions useless when updating to a newer version of firefox (via the `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`).

Of course the thinkers of Mozilla decided a plain setting in `about:config` would not do, to get rid of this limitation (to develop and use those extensions). Instead they tell to get a developer, or unbranded, or nighly version of the browser.

My question regarding to this is:
**Is there such a version of the Mozilla Firefox Browser in the Ubuntu repos?**. That is, is there one alternative version of Firefox in the Ubuntue repo that is the very same as stable, but simply has still the ability to run unsigned browser extensions?

PS: To avoid any comments on the line: "Just go ahead and hand them your extensions for signing, its not so bad". I do expressively not like their freedom limiting policy, and consequently rather go all the way to build each new release of theirs from the sources and patch out that stuff, then ever cooperating with Mozilla.

PSS: Since I must have missed that in that. The way to having a Firefox without the extension signing, I would not like to switch to be foreced into having two version. In effect that is what the "go fu*** yourself and install a Developer Edition" approach of Mozilla ends up being.

There has been the try iceweasel approach. Is iceweasel not having this "you cannot have free extensions" limitation that Mozilla put in the Firefox?

Comment: Take a look at Debian's IceWeasel. Not sure how many differences there are between it and FF, but worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox Developer Edition still has the override switch in about:config. You can install it manually, or from a PPA: [How do I install the Firefox Developer Edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition)

Comment: This is of course true, and I knew (and I should have stated with the question that the coercion to the Developer Edition, is nothing I really particularly like). Indeed asking the question was to really avoid having to use a PPA or different verions. Best would simply be a version 1:1 the seam as the current Firefox, but without the sigining shit

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see any other option unless you either use an old, insecure version of Firefox, or build your own hacked version from source.