# PPA for Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, firefox, ppa

Is there any PPA or repository available to install Firefox developer edition (stable and beta versions) in Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Comment: Do you need PPA or any installation media will suffice?

Comment: see this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is [this PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-aurora) for aurora builds if is fine for you.
You can do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore, after adding this ppa and reinstalling firefox I'm still stuck with the non-dev edition.

Comment: Warning: it will replace your current Firefox installation