# Firefox developer edition icon duplication in Gnome shell

Tags: gnome, firefox, launcher, icons

After installing Firefox Developer Edition using the [Aurora PPA method](https://askubuntu.com/a/548005/28930) on 16.04 I dragged the icon from Activities to the launcher sidebar for handy access. But when I click that I get a 2nd firefox icon appear in the sidebar:

[image: screenshot]

And every time I click the icon I added I get a new window. How can I get it to behave normally (i.e. when clicked it would display an already running firefox, or if there isn't one, start one)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

My solution is to edit the `firefox-dev.desktop` file, adding `--class firefox-aurora` to the Exec command and `StartupWMClass=firefox-aurora` as a new line.

The advantage of this one is that Firefox and Firefox Developer Edition will no longer share one icon if both are installed. If you name the class `firefox-aurora` the separate Firefox icon survives a restart e.g. after an upgrade.

If you have enabled Wayland support by setting `env MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` you also need to set `MOZ_APP_REMOTINGNAME=firefox-aurora` and add `--name firefox-aurora` to the Exec command.

A complete example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
GenericName=Developer Web Browser
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=env MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 MOZ_APP_REMOTINGNAME=firefox-aurora /home/user/Applications/firefox-developer-edition/firefox --class firefox-aurora --name firefox-aurora %U
Icon=/home/user/Applications/firefox-developer-edition/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Path=/home/user/Applications/firefox-developer-edition
StartupWMClass=firefox-aurora
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;Developer;
```

Comment: This is a great solution, particularly when you've got Developer Edition installed locally, you just need to create ~/.local/share/applications/firefox-dev.desktop and it can happily co-exist with the system-installed Firefox stable.

Comment: I've been having problems separating my Firefox icons in Ubuntu 18.04 and this fixed it.

Comment: In my case I also had to change the default `StartupWMClass=navigator` to `StartupWMClass=firefox` so it wouldn't also override my custom profile icon. That's because when you set `--class my-class` WM_CLASS becomes `navigator my-class` instead of `navigator firefox`. So `navigator` applies to all, but `firefox` is just the default.

Answer (score 12):

The WM_CLASS property of the window "Firefox-dev" doesn't match the file name of the `.desktop` file. You can check the WM_CLASS property using `xprop` and click on the opened Firefox's window.

So, here is what I did to make it work :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop /usr/share/applications/firefox-dev.desktop
```

Then you can add the new `firefox-dev.desktop` entry as favorite in you gnome-shell, and it will work.

Cheers !

Comment: Brilliant! I'm testing that out with some other awkward apps, too! Many thanks

Comment: Thanks, in my case WM_CLASS is `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "Firefox Developer Edition"` so the icon name for me worked as "/usr/share/applications/Firefox Developer Edition.desktop" and it seems to have stopped the icon duplication, for example, on session restore

Answer (score 9):

1. Launch Firefox Development Edition.
2. Open up the terminal and run `xprop WM_CLASS`. A `+` pointer will appear, Click anywhere on the Firefox Development Edition window.
3. You'll get some output like `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "Firefox Development Edition"`. Choose one of the classes, eg. Firefox Development Edition
4. Add the class as the value of StartupWMClass in the .desktop file present in `~/.local/share/applications/firefox_dev.desktop` . For example, `StartupWMClass=Firefox Development Edition`.  Don't forget to replace `firefox_dev` with the filename you have for your Firefox Development Edition.
5. Save the .desktop file, close the application and re-open it. There should now only be 1 icon in the launcher

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu 20.04 - here is what I did to fix this issue in my case - Firefox Developer Edition.

1. Entered this command in my terminal `xprop -name "{{window_name}}"`.

   *{{window_name}}* was **Firefox Developer Edition**.
2. Noted down the class name given on the line `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "{{class_name}}"`.

   *{{class_name}}* was **Firefox Developer Edition**.
3. Changed this line `Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox` to `Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox --class "{{class_name}}"` and added this line `StartupWMClass={{class_name}}` at the end of the *{{application.desktop}}* file

   *{{application.desktop}}* was located at
   **/home/{{user}}/.local/share/applications/firefoxDeveloperEdition.desktop**,
   substituted *{{class_name}}* with value found in previous steps and
   *{{user}}* with my user.