# Why does Firefox Developer Edition shortcut opens in new icon?

Tags: firefox, icons, .desktop, dock

I've been at this for hours now. Nothing works, .desktop file below. I don't know why, but I can't drag&drop the open firefox-dev icon to my favorites, only when I look for it in Applications windows and drag it from there. But that way it just opens a new icon instead. Before this issue gets closed for a mildly similar question, below are all of the solutions I've tried.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
StartupWMClass="firefox-aurora", "Firefox Developer Edition"
GenericName=Web Browser
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox %u
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;Favorites;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;NewIncognito
```

I've tried:

[Cannot add custom launcher to Ubuntu Dock ('Add to Favorites' option does not show up)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990833/cannot-add-custom-launcher-to-ubuntu-dock-add-to-favorites-option-does-not-sh)

[Ubuntu Dock adds a new icon when I open certain programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242536/ubuntu-dock-adds-a-new-icon-when-i-open-certain-programs)

[Duplicate icons for manually created GNOME launcher items](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403766/duplicate-icons-for-manually-created-gnome-launcher-items/635839#635839)

[How do I install the Firefox Developer Edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition/548005#548005)

[Firefox developer edition icon duplication in Gnome shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852613/firefox-developer-edition-icon-duplication-in-gnome-shell)

Comment: Read this it may help you.https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-create-desktop-shortcut-for-any-app-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts/

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunately. I tried using the default Firefox .desktop file as base and change the path but it doesn't work so yeah. This really sucks. I was really hoping Ubuntu is just install and go but this is still considered a basic thing and I've been troubleshooting for hours now. Obviously it's not all Ubuntu's fault Firefox developers have you download a tar instead of a .deb or something simple.

Comment: Then maybe look into Firefox support site.

Comment: Support sites are useless, though.

Comment: OK if you say so this is a support site and you posted your question here.

Comment: I meant the one Firefox themselves provide.. same what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setting StartupWMClass as

```
StartupWMClass=firefox-aurora
```

fixed my issue.

below StartupWMClasses doesn't work for me.

```
StartupWMClass="firefox-aurora", "Firefox Developer Edition"
StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition
```

my desktop entry

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox Developer 
GenericName=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox %u
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;X-Developer;
Comment=Firefox Developer Edition Web Browser.
StartupWMClass=firefox-aurora
StartupNotify=true
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem, then I removed Firefox Developer Edition from favorites, and I lost the ability to add it to favorites again (that option was missing from the right-click context menu).

This answer you linked to, [Firefox developer edition icon duplication in Gnome shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852613/firefox-developer-edition-icon-duplication-in-gnome-shell), helped me solve this issue, here's my `/usr/share/applications/firefox-developer-edition.desktop` (the naming could be relevant, not sure):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Developer Edition 
GenericName=Firefox Developer
Exec=/usr/bin/firefox-developer-edition/firefox --class "Firefox Developer Edition"
Terminal=false
Icon=/usr/bin/firefox-developer-edition/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;X-Developer;
Comment=Firefox Developer Edition Web Browser.
StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition
```

What fixed the problem for me was adding `--class "Firefox Developer Edition"` to the `Exec` line, but I'm guessing consistent naming matters as well.