# Firefox Developer Edition ppa not working

Tags: firefox, ppa

**Installing and updating Firefox Developer via PPA aurora channel**

Related: [How do I install the Firefox Developer Edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition) - it is just related, the question is not simple about how to install Firefox

---

So, I have added repo

```
ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
```

but I can't install current developer version (53). I'm still running the stable (51) official version.

Even in synaptic I can't see 53 version package. Could it be because on ppa https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-aurora, next to every package it shows (I need package for 16.10):

```
Failed to build: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64e
```

If it is so, how do you recommend to proceed? Install manually and wait?

---

20.9.2017 - Edit

- it looks like they started to update the channel again see comment https://askubuntu.com/a/936166/642778 bellow.
- added a title for clearance: Basically because the problem is really not just "how to install Firefox". *Yes, you can just download archive from the [official FF web](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/), decompress, run and FF will do self-auto updates.*

But there are some people, who want the source code too, people who are updating their FF extensions, or people who cannot have allowed auto-updates or many other reasons...

Comment: There aren't any built packages in the PPA at the moment. You can get FF aurora from https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/.

Comment: Very 'wierd' ppa as none of the previous successful builds are available though the packages are still there for the last one, (52). Ex. for 16.04 64 bit - https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-aurora/+build/11908207 Guess you'll have to wait till it gets good builds unless you want to download & install from previous page or from the beta channel ppa - https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-next

Comment: thx @doug for confirmation. I have downloaded manually from [here](https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-aurora-latest-ssl&os=linux64&lang=en-US) and installed conventionally to /opt. Maybe we should correct the outdated articles, that are recommending installing via ppa, or at least pin there some warning.

Comment: You could just download from firefox's page, extract the tar.gz file in some $PATH place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PPA was updated on September 17, 2017 (with version 57.0b1), after 5 months of inactivity. It's kind of a weird release schedule but that's probably related to the changes in release channels which are described here https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/04/simplifying-firefox-release-channels/

Answer (score 1):

Try via Ubuntu Make

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install ubuntu-make
umake web firefox-dev
```

src: http://sourcedigit.com/20695-how-to-install-firefox-developer-edition-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 1):

This ppa seems to be already deprecated (latest update was 3 months ago):

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-aurora

So I'm thinking there's no luck for installing through `apt-get` anymore. It needs to be downloaded manually from https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/developer/

Answer (score 0):

If you use ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa instead, then you can install 53.0a1 by installing the package firefox-trunk.

Comment: Apparently the person who posted the question knows how to add a ppa. But for other visitors it would be nice to have a solution which they could copy-paste to solve the problem.

Comment: @MadMike thx, exactly. And I do believe that developer version is different. Point is that [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Developer_Edition) is not working, following instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition) won't work either, and for people who has already added this ppa is bad, that they will not get  important update repairing some bug if there will occur one, and probably will not even notice that.