# Firefox Developer Edition fails to update itself automatically

Tags: 14.04, firefox

So my Firefox Developer Edition fails to update itself automatically although the settings show I allowed it to automatically install updates.

I first installed it manually into `/opt/firefox_dev/firefox` by following the [recommended procedure](https://askubuntu.com/a/548005/408652) and subsequently had to update it manually too -- which is very inconvenient, compared to automatic updates.

So I added the Mozilla PPA to my repositories and followed the procedure, but nothing changed: my FDE keeps on suggesting me, every couple of days or so, to download its latest update, while it should be done automatically, right?

What have I got wrong? Thank you.

P.S. I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, maybe that has something to do with the issue.

Comment: Also, maybe someone can kindly create and add some relevant tags to this question (firefox-developer-edition, fde, firefox-aurora), as my low ranking doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: If you've copied the files to /opt or /usr/local, both are owned by root, and aren't writable by regular users. To be able to auto update you need to install it in your home folder, or chown /opt or /usr/local. Alternatively, just download the new version and copy its files again, overwriting the old ones.

Comment: @mikewhatever Thank you. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to be able to give you some kudos.

Comment: Glad it helped. I've posted the above comment as answer, and you are welcome to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## I chose the `chown` fix, and it worked well for me.

Here is what you need to do:

1. Add Firefox Developer Edition PPA by following [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/a/548005/408652).
2. Quit all Firefox instances. Also, make sure there is no more `firefox` processes running in the background.
3. Give the ownership of Firefox Developer Edition directory to your user by running the following command:

```bsh
your_user_group_name = $(id --group --name)
sudo chown $USER:$your_user_group_name /path/to/firefox_dev -R
```

- `-R` stands for 'recursively'
- Your user group name may be the same as your user name. To check what groups your user belongs to, run `groups $USER`.

4. Finally run

   ```
    $ sudo apt update
    $ sudo apt install firefox
   ```

#### [2021 02 UPD]

I've been currently using Ubuntu 20.10 (groovy) and everything is fine.

Here's also the meta details and content of my [desktop launcher icon](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html):

```bsh
$ ll ~/.local/share/applications/firefox-developer.desktop 
-rw-r--r-- 1 MYUSERNAME MYUSERNAME 384 avril 20  2019 /home/MYUSERNAME/.local/share/applications/firefox-developer.desktop

$ cat ~/.local/share/applications/firefox-developer.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
Icon=/home/MYUSERNAME/.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
TryExec=/home/MYUSERNAME/.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev/firefox
Exec=firefox-developer
Comment=Firefox Aurora with Developer tools
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition
```

Comment: Would this still be available for ubuntu 20.04? I tried this and the FDE launcher icon just disappeared. There is only the default Firefox one. Are there maybe any more changes that need to be done on `~/.local/share/applications/firefox_dev.desktop`?

Comment: @DariusP see update above

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into it. I also tried to install the PPA, but didn't manage to. So I did with **Ubuntu Make** and it worked. 
In the `firefox-dev.desktop` file, it only works for me if I remove the `TryExec` line and rewrite the `Exec` to `Exec=/home/MYUSERNAME/.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev/firefox` .

Answer (score 3):

If you've copied files to `/opt` or `/usr/local`, both are owned by root, and aren't writable by regular users. To be able to auto update, you need to install it in your home folder, or chown `/opt` or `/usr/local`.

Alternatively, just download the new version and copy its files again, overwriting old ones.

Answer (score 2):

I’d prefer ACL over regular permissions if your kernel supports it.

Just run:

```bsh
sudo setfacl -Rm u:$USER:rwx /opt
# Or
sudo setfacl -Rm u:$USER:rwx /opt/firefox_dev

# -R     set the ACL permissions recursively
# -m     modify (and thus set) the new permissions
# $USER  is the currently running user; you may want
#        to change this
# rwx    the permissions you want to add the $USER;
#        skip any letters to that permission
#        from $USER
```

For more info use `man setfacl` and `man getfacl`.