# How to install firefox developer edition using terminal?

Tags: command-line, firefox, windows-subsystem-for-linux

There are many similar questions out there but none of them have mentioned any installation process using terminal. Please give some hint, what are the command line to download Firefox developer edition directly.

Apart from these whenever I download from web, it does not appear in my desktop or app menu. I have to go to the file then it is working.

Help!!
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22)   *There are answers in this that assume it's all from CLI/command line*

Comment: Try this https://dev.to/harrsh2124/how-to-setup-firefox-developer-edition-on-ubuntu-4inp, I had it done for Ubuntu 20.04.Maybe it is different from 22.04, because in 22.04 they are using snap to install firefox

Comment: There are LOTS of installation tutorials that use the terminal. Perhaps you really want a tutorial that doesn't use a *package manager*, but tells you how to install the upstream binary yourself manually. Or perhaps you want something else; it's not clear.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  I notice that you have this tagged [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux], but you don't mention that anywhere in your question.  Are you really using WSL?  If so, please edit your question to include that information, including Windows version.  Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the Firefox Developer Edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/) Here is the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1372744/) that I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from options to [install Firefox using the Debian APT system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22), i.e. as a .deb package, you can install [from mozilla builds](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux#w_install-firefox-from-mozilla-builds-for-advanced-users). Using the terminal only, the process can go like:

```
wget -O FirefoxSetup.tar.bz2 https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-devedition-latest-ssl&os=linux64
sudo tar xvf FirefoxSetup.tar.bz2 -C /opt/
```

This will install the files in `/opt/firefox`. If you want a different folder, e.g. `firefox-devedition` then you can instead extract the files locally, and move/rename the extracted directory `firefox`:

```
tar xvf FirefoxSetup.tar.bz2
sudo mv firefox /opt/firefox-devedition
```

You can determine the URL for the product you need by selecting your product on the [Firefox downloads](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/#product-desktop-beta) page. Then right-click the Download button to copy the link.

To add a launcher in your menu system, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/548005/558158).