# Firefox Developer Edition doesn't work

Tags: firefox, windows-subsystem-for-linux, browser

A few days ago I installed firefox developer edition by [this method](https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-install-firefox-developer-edition-on-ubuntu-22-04-or-20-04/) (downloading and unzipping the .bz2 file). That install worked well.

After some time Firefox notified me to update, so I deleted `/opt/firefox` and reinstalled it [using ubuntu-make (umake)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition/548005#548005). While doing so, I accidentally installed firefox by running `sudo apt update firefox`, so I ran `sudo apt remove firefox` to delete it.

When the `umake` install didn't work well, I removed `~/.local/share/umake/` and reinstalled it the [first way](https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-install-firefox-developer-edition-on-ubuntu-22-04-or-20-04/). But it still isn't working as well as before the update. What should I do?

I'm using WSL.

What isn't working:

- [minimize/maximize buttons are gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zts9.png)
- [menu bar isn't working (every button in menu doesn't work)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCOu0.png)
- [when I type something mouse cursor turn into black box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90CAy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get purge firefox` then reinstall by your initial method.

When following a guide to install a thing, it's worth considering it's instructions for the update process (step 7).

Comment: I tried, but it still doesn't work. Is there any other way?

Comment: when you removed the `umake` install you write that you removed `~/.local/share/umake/`, but I'm struggling to relate that to the guide in source 2. Did you run `umake web firefox-dev -r`, or did you perhaps run `sudo rm -r /opt/firefox_dev/` (adjusted to your address use)?

Comment: when i installed by umake, i'd already removed `/opt/firefox`. and when removed umake install, I ran both `sudo rm -r ~/.local/share/umake/` and `umake -r seb firefox-dev` because result of `whereis firefox-dev` was `/.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev/firefox`.